# Can you enable 32-bit version of Edge on a 64-bit machine?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I am working on a project where we are using a browser plugin that only supports 32-bit browsers, and I have to find out how it will work with the new Edge browser.

I found the following when searching if there was a 32-bit version of the Edge browser ([source](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2015/05/11/microsoft-edge-browser-security.aspx)):

> The Edge browser will be a 64-bit browser by default, except if run on
>   a 32-bit processor

Is there a way of starting Edge in 32-bit mode even though I'm on a 64-bit machine?

Comment: Seeing as Windows 10 is so new, and technically not released yet, there may be no definitive answer to this question yet. I took a look at where the actual file location for Edge was and it's in `C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_.....`. I see no alternative file, just `MicrosoftEdge.exe` so perhaps you can only use the version that's installed with your Windows 10.

Comment: I am going to delete my original comment.  Edge does not have support plugins as of today nor did it have support in July 2015.  As the article clearly indicates the only way to run a 32-bit version of Edge is to have a 32-bit installation of Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Under `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer` you can find the "old" 32-bit version of Internet Explorer.

Comment: The author wanted to run a 32-bit version of Edge not Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, on 64-bit Windows machines, the 32-bit applications install to `C:\Program Files (x86)` folder, so you'll find the 32-bit Internet Explorer in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer` folder.

Regarding Edge, it seems Microsoft sites only confirm what you already found: that Edge can run on either 32-bit or 64-bit systems. I suppose asking your question to Microsoft suppport would be the best solution.